# How do I click on an edit menu using UITest and Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode-ui-testing

In my UITest I can long-press in a textview which pops up an edit menu with the two options Select and Select All. How do I choose one of these? Here is my code and it fails on the third line.

```
app.textViews["noteText"].tap()
app.textViews["noteText"].press(forDuration: 2)
app.staticTexts["Select All"].tap()
```

Comment: What's the failure?

Comment: UI Testing Failure - No matches found for "Select All" StaticText

Comment: In the LLDB console when you have a breakpoint set at that line, what's the output of the command `po app`?

Comment: The output is too long to post as a comment however there is no reference to "select all".

Comment: How about `app.descendantsMatchingType(.Any).elementMatchingType(.Any, identifier: "Select All")` ?

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Once your answer had been updated to Swift 3 it worked perfectly: `app.descendants(matching: .any).element(matching: .any, identifier: "Select All").tap()`. If you add this as a proposed answer I will mark it as answered.

Comment: Done! Didn't realize you were on Swift 3, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift 2.3 answer: `app.descendantsMatchingType(.Any).elementMatchingType(.Any, identifier: "Select All")`

Swift 3 answer: `app.descendants(matching: .any).element(matching: .any, identifier: "Select All").tap()`

It's not clear why different queries return different results, but this query consistently returns the maximal superset of all queries in my experience and can be used whenever an identifier is globally unique across the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `UIAction.accessibilityIdentifier` seems to work:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
button.changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = true
let action = UIAction(title: "Action") { _ in
    // handler
}
action.accessibilityIdentifier = "action"
let menu = UIMenu(children: [action])
button.menu = menu
```

And in the UI test:

```
app.buttons["action"].tap()
```